# How to make a responsive with a grid of 1,2,3 rows

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

With the following code the responsive grid turn from one row to three and I would like to do one row to two rows and then 3 raw if the screen is large. What is the best way to do it ? In pure Css and not with bootstrap. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```css
/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 1.6%;
}

.col:first-child {margin-left: 0}

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.group:after {
  clear: both;
}

.group {
  zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 */
}

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 {
  width: 100%;
}

.span_2_of_3 {
  width: 66.1%;
}

.span_1_of_3 {
  width: 32.2%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH AT LESS THAN 480 PIXELS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .col {margin: 1% 0 1% 0%}
  .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 {width: 100%}
}
```

```html
<div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    This is column 1
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    This is column 2
  </div>
  <div class="col span_1_of_3">
    This is column 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet uses the float method you had started with and cleaned it up a bit. Flexbox and inline-block are other ways to implement responsive columns, but there's no best way; it depends on the situation.

You don't need numbered classes on the columns. Percentage padding and margins can be tricky so I used 5px. Setting a negative margin on the container means you don't need to remove margin on the first or last columns.

One big issue though is blank space in the container so I set that font-size to 0.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .section {
      clear: both;
      padding: 0px;
      margin: -5px;
      font-size: 0;
    }
    
    .col {
      font-size: 16px;
      float: left;
      margin: 5px;
      width: calc( 33.33% - 10px);
    }
    
    .group {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .group:after {
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .group {
      zoom: 1;
      /* For IE 6/7 */
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .col {
        width: calc( 50% - 10px);
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
      .col {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="section group">
    <div class="col">
      This is column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      This is column 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      This is column 3
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
body {margin: 0}

.group {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* enables their wrapping */
}

.col {flex: 1} /* each 33.33% of the parent's width (3 columns) until the break at 768px */

.first {background: red}
.second {background: green}
.third {background: blue}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .col {flex: 0 1 50%} /* each 50% of the parent's width (2 columns) */
}

/* if you want for the third column to take the remaining space, just change the first number to 1 to enable growing/expanding of flex-items */
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .col {flex-basis: 100%} /* each 100% of the parent's width (1 column) */
}

/* The flex property is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis. The second and third parameters (flex-shrink and flex-basis) are optional. Default: "flex: 0 1 auto" */
```

```html
<div class="section group">
  <div class="col first">
    This is column 1
  </div>
  <div class="col second">
    This is column 2
  </div>
  <div class="col third">
    This is column 3
  </div>
</div>
```

I assume you are talking about *columns*, but correct me if I am wrong and I will modify my answer.